# Give in the $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ linear transformations with the following property:

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Give in the $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ linear transformations with the following property:

$$\operatorname{Ker}(\varphi) = \operatorname{Im}(\psi) = \{ (x,x): x \in \mathbb{R} \} \qquad \text{and}\qquad\operatorname{Im}(\varphi)=\operatorname{Ker}(\psi)=\{ (x,-x): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

Can I maybe somehow write a linear combination of the informations abouve, or in which way can I find those linear transformations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a systematic approach, notice that
$\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$
is generated by $(1,1)$, and the other set by $(1,-1)$, and $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are linearly independent.

Hence $\{\beta_1:=(1,1),\,\beta_2:=(1,-1)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R$. Then write every $v\in\mathbb R^2$ uniquely as $a\beta_1+b\beta_2$. Then the mapping that takes $v$ to $b\beta_2$ (respectively $a\beta_1$) is a linear transformation and together they have the desired properties.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

$$\varphi(x,y)=(x-y,y-x)$$ and $$\psi(x,y)=(x+y,x+y).$$

Comment: Can you maybe explain me just briefly how did you get it? I still can't understand it unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to write out the conditions in matrix form.

$Im(\psi)=\{(x,x)\}$ implies the matrix of $\psi$ is of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\a&b\end{bmatrix}$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, not both zero. [The image of $\psi$ is the span of its columns.]

$Ker(\psi)=\{(x,-x)\}$ then implies $a-b=0$. [Write out what the condition implies: $\psi(x,-x)=0$.] So $\psi=a\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ for some $a \ne 0$.

Similar reasoning will give you $\varphi = c \begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ for some $c \ne 0$.